# C# Int and math not returning full value

Tags: c#

```
Int64 c1 = Convert.ToInt64(csvdeep[1]);
Int64 division = 1024;
string results = Math.Abs(c1 / division / division / division).ToString();
```

My `c1` is `10201841664` and `results` is `"9"`.

I'd perfer to get the 2nd two decimal places so my real result would be 9.50.  Any tips on how I could get the 2 decimal places?

Answer (score 12):

That is the result of integer division in .NET - when dividing two integers you always get an integer.

You need at least one of the operands to be a floating point type (float, double, decimal) in order for the result to be a floating point.

```
Int64 c1 = Convert.ToInt64(csvdeep[1]);
double division = 1024.0m;
string results = Math.Abs(c1 / division / division / division).ToString();
```

The result of this will probably have more decimal places than you want so you will need to use a format string in the call to `ToString`:

```
string results = Math.Abs(c1 / division / division / division).ToString("0.00");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
string results = Math.Abs(((double)c1)/division/division/division)
    .ToString("0.00");
```

By converting the first value (`c1`) to a floating point value rather than an integer, you force the result of the division to become floating point as well.

That would then force the use of `Math.Abs(double)` rather than `Math.Abs(long)`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Int64 c1 = 10201841664;
Int64 division = 1024;
string results = Math.Abs((decimal)c1/division/division/division).ToString("0.00");
```

You could even go for

```
Int64 c1 = 10201841664;
Int64 division = 1024;
string results = Math.Abs((double)c1 / Math.Pow((double)division, 3)).ToString("0.00");
```

Comment: @astander I originally had the same syntax (with double instead of decimal). Wouldn't you need another set of parens around `(decimal)c1`? Currently this would evaluate` c1/division/division/division` (which returns an int) and then cast the int value to a double (with no values in the decimal places).

Comment: Sorry, I was 4th because I entered the code into an open solution. It works X-)

Answer (score 0):

You are using integer division here. That's why its not showing any decimal places.